# MVC - Should be there a master View, Model and Controller or should they be implementation-specific?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm interested in the concept, not the implementation. Consider a `CarBookingRequest` scenario where user through an interface requests for booking a car. Let's discuss it under the following constraint and taking only `View` in perspective by keeping `Controller` and `Model` simple:

- There is one controller class/code which contains all the functions representing relevant actions
- There is one model class/code that deals only with single database with few tables (no other data models)

There can be many interfaces through which a request can be made:

**1. Desktop Application**

A user clicks a `Button` that fires the `Click` event which in turn is pre-programmed to make a call to `BookingController` with request `NewBooking`. Something like:

```
 Event OnClick() { 
    C = New BookingController
    C.Request('NewBooking')
 }
```

**2. Mobile Application**

A user taps a `Button` that fires the `Touch` event which in turn is pre-programmed to make a call to the same `BookingController` with request `NewBooking`. Something like:

```
 EventListener OnTouch() { 
    C = New BookingController
    C.Request('NewBooking')
 }
```

**3. Vending Machine**

A user presses a `PushButton` on the machine that fires the event which is pre-programmed to make a call to the same `BookingController` with request `NewBooking`. Something like:

```
 Event OnPress() { 
    C = New BookingController
    C.Request('NewBooking')
 }
```

Assume similar implementation for a **Web Interface** and **Service Interface** where the request is made by another system or a scheduled task. Obviously all these implementation are different versions of **BookingViews** written in very different languages and platform. Now if I knew these implementations beforehand and I am making a Booking MVC, what should be my View, Controller and Model Class like? or how many? and why?

Should I have a "Main" `BookingView` class that has a function such as:

```
 Function CallController(Command) { 
    If Command = 'NewBooking' {
       Return New BookingController
    }
    or some good implementation of controller/action registry to fetch appropriate controller
 }
```

and every specific `View` should in-turn call this function which then will call the `BookingController` as:

```
 Event OnClick { 
    C = MainView.CallConroller('NewBooking')
 }
```

Or should each `View` call the controller separately in its own way?

May be too many questions but I am of the view that my View, Controller and Model should be reusable and every new `Interface` (Mobile, Machine or Web) should require only their specific handling of the `View` (events or displays) while the connecting and fetch data code remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The core idea of MVC patterns is to **separate** the three aspects of the application - model, view and controller - **from** each other.

The way you describe your solution, doesn't seem to adhere to this principle. Let me suggest a method that helps you to achieve good MVC, following these rules. I am describing the generic rules, you can then modify according to the specifics of your application, frameworks etc:

- **Your controller should not know about the views**. This rule helps to separate "view" from control. If you follow this rule, your controller, instead of worrying about types of client, can just return one type of resource (e.g. a JSON resource, in this case a Booking). Then, each client (Web, mobile, machine) has to handle presentation of this resource, whichever way they want. But the important point is that, it is not the concern of controller.
- **Your Model should not know about the controller**. The concern of Model is **to implement a car booking**. It does not know what is being done with it (like whether a controller wants to access it to then pass it to someone else or so). For example, it may have an interface such as

  CarBooking:

  constructor();

  book();

  unbook();

  ...

It performs the business logic of constructing a request, booking a request or removing a booking. **Period**.

How do you achieve this, proper separation of Model, View and Controller? Well, one method is to start from within, and then move outward. That is, start from Model, then controller, then view. In reality, you may not do it in this order as you has to consider all of these aspects. But, what I am saying is more in the logical sense.

Comment: Thanks. If Controller is separate from View then **what** activates (or call) the controller when a command is given such as `CreateBooking`? Doesn't Controller intermediates between Model and View?

Comment: Actually, the core idea of the MVC pattern - no matter its implementation - is to separate only two application aspects from each other: UI and business logic.